# Angular Ng duplicate Repeater

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a seat booking system in angular. My script generate multidimensional arrays from rows and columns. Every thing is working fine except when I retrieve the json data from database and tries to print the seating system, It returns me duplicate repeater error.

Here is the repeater code I am using:

```
<table class="em_venue_seating">

                <tr ng-repeat="row in term.seats" class="row isles_row_spacer" id="row{{$index}}" ng-style="{'margin-top':row[0].rowMargin}"> 


                    <td class="row_selection_bar" ng-click="selectRow($index)">
                        <div>Select Row</div>
                    </td>

                    <td ng-repeat="seat in row" class="seat isles_col_spacer" ng-class="seat.type" id="ui{{$parent.$index}}-{{$index}}" 
                        ng-dblclick="selectColumn($index)" ng-style="{'margin-left':seat.columnMargin}"
                        ng-click="selectSeat(seat, $parent.$index, $index)">
                        {{seat.uniqueIndex}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

My json string which I am parsing before using is:

```
seats:"[[{"type":"reserve","price":9,"uniqueIndex":"0-0","row":0,"col":0,"columnMargin":0,"rowMargin":0,"$$hashKey":"object:327"},{"type":"reserve","price":9,"uniqueIndex":"0-1","row":0,"col":1,"columnMargin":0,"rowMargin":0,"$$hashKey":"object:328"}],[{"type":"general","price":9,"uniqueIndex":"1-0","row":1,"col":0,"columnMargin":0,"rowMargin":0,"$$hashKey":"object:333"},{"type":"general","price":9,"uniqueIndex":"1-1","row":1,"col":1,"columnMargin":0,"rowMargin":0,"$$hashKey":"object:334"}]]"
```

System is returning duplicate repeater issue for my first ng-repeat. Tried to use "track by $index" but it is causing infinite loop.

Any help will be appreciated. I am new to Angular world.

Comment: can you post your parsed json (not as a string with hashkey)

Comment: You can check from http://www.jsoneditoronline.org

Comment: i have checked this json string that you posted, works fine for me, without any duplicate errors

Comment: That's strange. The only difference is that my object is retrieved from database and then parsed. Can you please share your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5596/

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will analyse it shortly.

Comment: Can you show the code that is generating the multidimensional array? You probably have two references to the same object somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, That was the case. I was using two references. Thanks you Sir.

Comment: Glad you solved it :)